# Extending the Hellinger Distance of discrete probability distributions to multivariate distributions

Tags: distance, joint-distribution, metric

For two discrete probability distributions P=(p1..pk) and Q=(q1...qk), their Hellinger distance is defined as

$$H(P,Q)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k(\sqrt{p_i}-\sqrt{q_i})^2}$$

could this be extended into bivariate

$$H(P,Q)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}(\sqrt{p_{ij}}-\sqrt{q_{ij}})^2}$$

If this is wrong, is there any other distance metric to measure the distance of such multivariate probability distribution?

Comment: Every bivariate discrete distribution can be treated as univariate.

Comment: treat as univariate? you mean, change them into a vector, pij-> pk, qij->qk ?

Comment: $P(X=x_{i},Y=y_{j})=p_{ij} \equiv P(Z=k)=p_k$, where $k$ is the number of combination $ij$.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm still feel confused in my real application, could you read my question on this site, and give me some suggestion.^.^

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132562/distance-measure-method-to-measure-the-distance-between-two-matrixesprobability

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the Hellinger distance do not depend on dimension, it is the same in every dimension. So the answer to your question is YES, you can compute with a double sum as you propose.